# Qt Installer Framework - Removing the Maintenance Tool

Tags: qt, installation, qt-installer

I'm using the Qt Installer Framework (2.0.3) to create an installer my program. Everything works fine, and my program installs perfectly.

However, I'd like to remove (or not install at all) the maintenance tool that is included by default. I have read the documentation and examples, and have searched the web but I haven't found any solutions to this problem. The closest thing I have found is the "MaintenanceToolName" element in the configuration file. I would have also expected an option to prevent the maintenance tool from being installed altogether. It would also be great if I could remove the Licenses folder too.

So in short: Is there a way to remove or prevent the maintenance tool (and its associated files) from being installed?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you been able to avoid the Maintenance Tool?

Comment: @Silicomancer No, not yet, though I haven't visited this issue in quite some time so there may have been some advancements since I posed the question.

Answer (score 1):

No. I have looked through [the source code](https://github.com/qtproject/installer-framework/blob/master/src/libs/installer/packagemanagercore.cpp#L418), and although there is a tempting `m_needToWriteMaintenanceTool` there isn't any way to stop it being written.

Comment: I went through the source code and I was able to stop it being written when building it myself

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to build it from source in order to disable that option
Go to the [function](https://github.com/qtproject/installer-framework/blob/711a412f52667d90aa49891e6b8207e548f33463/src/libs/installer/packagemanagercore.cpp#L464) `void PackageManagerCore::writeMaintenanceTool()` and and the [function](https://github.com/qtproject/installer-framework/blob/711a412f52667d90aa49891e6b8207e548f33463/src/libs/installer/packagemanagercore_p.cpp#L1112) `void PackageManagerCorePrivate::writeMaintenanceToolBinary()` and just add a `return` in the beginning of the function to disable it and the maintenance tool won't be included.

Worked for me, but it didn't reduce the size of the resulting installer as I was expecting though.